# Reason for parametric variation in a power system

Tags: power, frequency, control, pid-controller, load

Let us take an example of a single area power system consisting of a governor, noon-reheated turbine, load and machine, droop characteristics.

It is written in the literature that `T_g, T_t, T_p, R`, i.e, the time constant of the governor, turbine and plant may vary, thus there is a large parametric uncertainty in this system. Thus, we often design fractional order PID as compared to a classical PID for such a system.

My doubt is, that under what conditions and why (or how) do these parameters vary ?

Comment: Can you provide a source or the direct citation? This perplex me. The power planner use the fact that they know the W/s ramp up of their plant to do a proper dispatch of power production.

Comment: The only thing i Can think if you want to avoid aggressive governor because you might end up having 2 governor fighting each other even if you have a Power Stabilizer system.